Unable to create incoming web hook in new MS Teams
I'm trying to create an incoming web hook in MS Teams, but after adding it, the configuration window popped up as blank without any error message. I've been trying to find a solution online but have very little luck. Please help!
blank webhook configuration window
I followed this discussion (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329445/unable-to-see-create-outgoing-webhook-from-channel) and ensured that I have access to Web Hook app on MS Teams. However, I got stuck on the creation step and have no further details to progress from here.

O365 Connectors Substrate team is aware of this issue and there is an ICM raised to fix this. Once this is fixed, we will notify you in this thread. Thanks! Additionally, O365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated and notifications from this service will stop. Effective August 15th, 2024: All new Connector creation will be blocked within all clouds and effective October 1st, 2024: All connectors within all clouds will stop working. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/

Could you please share your Tenant Id where the issue is happening?

According to latest update from engineering team, you can start using teams web to create Incoming Webhook & RSS connectors. However, the fix for Teams Desktop client is under investigation.

According to latest update from engineering team, the bug has been fixed in both Teams web and desktop client. Thanks!

If you are doing it on the Teams application, I would suggest doing it on your browser instead. It worked for me, I hope it will for you too !

yes, I also got it working from browser: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/why-cant-teams-add-incoming-webhooks/b74a68b0-93aa-4462-ba41-1e8d0fdc3c55
